# Как записать структуру в файл и считать её обратно?

Tags: c++

Необходимо записать структуру в файл, а потом снова использовать ёё.

```
struct Lesson {

  int number;
  string day;
  string lessonName;
  string groupName;
  string teacher;
  string classroom;
};
```

Comment: открываете файл, записываете поочередно все члены структуры и закрываете файл. Нужно будет взять из файла: открываем файл, читаем из него члены и записываем в поля. Все просто.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос о том, что бы просто в середине кода записать структуру в файл, то она сама по себе не перейдет из памяти в файл, а будет скопирована, то есть её можно будет далее использовать.

Если же вопрос о том, как вывести её в файл, а затем, при необходимости, считать её из файла, то надо лишь придумать, как Вы планируете различать конец одной строки от другой. Например, если полагается, что все переменные типа `string` не будут иметь символа перехода на новую строку, то, вполне удобным будет вариант вывести построчно в файл. И потом построчно же и считывать.

Что касается аргумента типа `int`, то для преобразования строки к числу есть такие функции, как `atoi`, либо `strtol`. Либо сразу подразумевать, что считываете Вы число. Компьютер знает, как считанные символы преобразовать к числу

Answer (score 0):

Раз это C++, я бы добавил код записи и чтения прямо в структуру:

```
struct Lesson {
    int number;
    string day;
    string lessonName;
    string groupName;
    string teacher;
    string classroom;

    static ofstream& writeString(ofstream& os, const string& s) {
        size_t l;
        l = s.length();
        os.write((const char*)&l, sizeof(l));
        os.write(s.c_str(), l);
        return os;
        }

    static ifstream& readString(ifstream& is, string& s) {
        size_t l;
        is.read((char*)&l, sizeof(l));
        char* mem = new char[l];
        is.read(mem, l);
        s.assign(mem, l);
        delete[] mem;
        return is;
        }


    ofstream& writeToFile(ofstream& os) const {
        os.write((const char*)&number, sizeof(number));
        writeString(os, day);
        writeString(os, lessonName);
        writeString(os, groupName);
        writeString(os, teacher);
        return writeString(os, classroom);
        }

    ifstream& readFromFile(ifstream& is) {
        is.read((char*)&number, sizeof(number));
        readString(is, day);
        readString(is, lessonName);
        readString(is, groupName);
        readString(is, teacher);
        return readString(is, classroom);
        }


    };
```

Ну и, конечно, файлы должны быть открыты как бинарные.